# Google Cloud Run suitable to run Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

We have a Docker container that packages a Java Spring Boot application. The application sometimes takes about 40 seconds to start.

Is Google Cloud Run suitable to run such a "heavyweight" application?

Let's say it'd be scaled down to 0 replicas, then the following would take 40 seconds upwards to be processed. Or is there some logic on Cloud Run's side to avoid such a case.

Comment: Perhaps the use of GraalVM can improve start times

Comment: There is no answer to your question based upon the information provided. Cloud Run cold start (for my tests) averages 2,000 ms. This means your application is taking 38 seconds to start up. Profile your application to reduce startup times. If your application takes more than a few seconds to start up, then it is probably not a good fit for Cloud Run.

Comment: Here is a good performance article on different Java frameworks including Spring for Cloud Run ... https://medium.com/google-cloud/java-frameworks-performances-on-cloud-run-eb243fd84a5c

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't avoid the cold start cost when Cloud Run starts a new virtual server instance.  If 40 seconds is unacceptable overhead to handle an incoming "cold" request, then you might want to pay for a servers that stay running 24/7.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely improve Spring Boot startup time by doing a few things. The easiest being the increase of CPU resource. [Spring Boot startup time scales significantly based on CPU available](https://medium.com/faun/java-application-optimization-on-kubernetes-on-the-example-of-a-spring-boot-microservice-cf3737a2219c).

We were running Spring Boot with lots of dependencies on Kubernetes. It took 10 minutes to startup with `0.1` vcpu. In a world where we need to scale up and down quickly, this was not acceptable. But once we increased it to `1` vcpu, it dropped to 1 minute. It would appear that it scales fairly linearly to the amount of CPU provided. This obviously costs more money, so it depends on what your budget will allow.

You could also use some more complex configuration to reduce the startup time. There are several benchmarks comparing different JVM options, dependencies, and Spring configuration in a lot of detail. I'll link them below for you to have a look and assess what is worth the time.

[Benchmarks for Spring Boot Start Up](https://github.com/dsyer/spring-boot-startup-bench)

[Let's make SpringBoot app start faster](https://dev.to/bufferings/lets-make-springboot-app-start-faster-k9m)

If you are open to using TypeScript, there is a very similar framework you can use called [Loopback](https://loopback.io/doc/index.html). The patterns used reminds me a lot of Spring and being in TypeScript, it boots up incredibly quickly. My time-to-first-request to the closest region (about 2000 km away) was just 2 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

You can't avoid that 40 second spin up time. So it really depends on how often you're calling it.

We use spring boot + gke, cloud run would make no sense unless the code was used like once a week. (That's maybe dramatic, but you get it).

If you have end users interacting with that, it's probably unacceptable. If it's just an API endpoint for some automation then you're only annoying skynet.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid cold starts by setting the minimum number instances higher than 0 in cloud run. It'll cost a lot more but your last instance won't shut down when idle.

I haven't run spring boot in cloud run myself but you can scale both cpu and ram pretty high, and with a minimum of 5 instances it should be able to auto scale fast enough even with 40 s cold start.